# Looking for ways to use "ASCII/Unicode art" to generate simple chart within the SQL resultset using a basic SQL client

Tags: sql, postgresql

I often have to pour through data to look for some pattern. It would be nice if I can see a quick chart inline or even across lines.

I can think of several ways to do it. For example:

1. In one column print a character say '*' n number of times where n is
   proportional to the number you want to visualize. This will
   generate a vertical bar graph.
2. Use special unicode characters that look like bars of different heights and use the appropriate character corresponding to the value you want to plot. Print multiple such characters side by side. This will generate an inline bar graph or [sparkline](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/).

While I can go ahead and implement something crude myself, I thought I might as well ask. Perhaps something like this already exists.

I am using PostgreSQL but the problem is fairly generic.

Comment: https://periscope.io/blog/ascii-art-charts-in-the-terminal.html

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set